# Covariant assignment not working

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I am trying to generalize the notification of changes to the properties of an object via an `IObservable<T>` but that's besides the point of the question. The point of the question is: the following assignment I make reports an invalid covariance error:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(
                      string propertyName, 
                      T oldValue, T newValue)
{
    IPropertyChangedNotification<Student, object> notification = 
        new PropertyChangedNotification<Student, T>(this,
        propertyName, oldValue, newValue);

    ...
}
```

This reports:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 
>   `PropertyChangedNotification<UsingSubjectToWatchProperty.Student, T>`
>   to  `IPropertyChangedNotification<UsingSubjectToWatchProperty.Student,
>   object>`.  An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Here is the complete code:

```
class Student
{
    private ISubject<IPropertyChangedNotification<Student, object>> _subject = 
       new Subject<IPropertyChangedNotification<Student, object>>();;
    private string _name = null;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {

            var oldValue = _name;
            _name = value;

            OnPropertyChanged<string>("Name", oldValue, _name);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(string propertyName, T oldValue, T newValue)
    {
        IPropertyChangedNotification<Student, object> notification = 
            new PropertyChangedNotification<Student, T>(this,
            propertyName, oldValue, newValue);

        _subject.OnNext(notification);
    }
}

public class PropertyChangedNotification<TDeclaringType, TPropertyType>
    : IPropertyChangedNotification<TDeclaringType, TPropertyType>
{
    public PropertyChangedNotification(TDeclaringType declaringObject, 
        string propertyName, 
        TPropertyType oldValue, 
        TPropertyType newValue)
    {
        DeclaringObject = declaringObject;
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        OldValue = oldValue;
        NewValue = newValue;
    }

    public TDeclaringType DeclaringObject { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public TPropertyType OldValue { get; protected set; }
    public TPropertyType NewValue { get; protected set; }
}

public interface IPropertyChangedNotification<TDeclaringType, out TPropertyType>
{
    TDeclaringType DeclaringObject { get; set; }
    string PropertyName { get; set; }

    TPropertyType OldValue { get; }
    TPropertyType NewValue { get; }
}
```

**PS:** This is not production code. Just practice stuff.

Comment: `<Student, object>` != `<Student, T>`. Why do you need first one? Simply use `var`.

Comment: As pointed out `object`!=`T`. As a set of side notes; Try to avoid using subjects. And out of interest turning INPC events into Observable sequences has been solved a dozen ways ;-) Here are some for free https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/blob/master/Model/PropertyChange.md

Comment: @LeeCampbell: Thank you, Lee. I read your article and enjoyed it. I was trying to do it my own way. I am trying to make all kinds of permutations and combinations and doing all the examples in your book and then some more that I make up on my own. :-)

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but the argument `object != T` does not hold in the face of the covariant generic type parameter `TPropertyType` in the interface `IPropertyChangedNotification<TDeclaringType, out TPropertyType> where TPropertyType: class`? It just so happens that restricting `TPropertyType` to reference types does me no good.

Comment: Sure, but your code doesn't have the `where TPropertyType:class` clause.

Comment: That's true. Was just saying. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Covariance and contravariance are only supported for reference types (to convert a value type to an `Object` it would need to be boxed).

So you would need to constrain `T` to `class`:

```
void OnPropertyChanged<T>(string propertyName, T oldValue, T newValue)
    where T : class { ... }
```

Alternatively, you could just use `new PropertyChangedNotification<Student, object>()`.

A third option would be to have an interface without `TProperty`:

```
public interface IPropertyChangedNotification<TDeclaringType>
{
    TDeclaringType DeclaringObject { get; set; }
    string PropertyName { get; set; }
}

public interface IPropertyChangedNotification<TDeclaringType, out TPropertyType>
    :  IPropertyChangedNotification<TDeclaringType>
{
    TPropertyType OldValue { get; }
    TPropertyType NewValue { get; }
}
```

Then use it in the `Subject` (since you'd have to cast it to a concrete type anyhow when you subscribe):

```
ISubject<IPropertyChangedNotification<Student>>
```

Comment: Bummer! Is there an *inexpensive* way to go about this?